# How would you loop through queues with slightly different names?

Tags: java, for-loop

First off, this is a small part to a huge programming assignment in one of my classes.

I have 10 different priority queues. Like prio1, prio2, prio3. Each of these queues is sorted by a process number.

If I want to check and see if process #16 with priority of 3 needs to be replaced with a higher priority process, what would be the easiest way?

```
private static void checkHigherQueues( int runningPrio, int runningPid, int cpu ){
   for( int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
       if ( prio(i).peek() == null ){
       }else if( prio(i).peek() < runningPid && i == runningPrio){
           release from cpu....
       }
```

To answer some of the questions:

I am using a different queue for each priority because I didn't know you could make a priority queue sort with two comparators. This is the code I'm using for the queue, how would I change it to sort first by priority and then by pid?

```
prio1 = new PriorityQueue<>(1, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare( String x, String y ){
                int first = Integer.parseInt(x);
                int second = Integer.parseInt(y);
                return second - first;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are your *priority* queues sorted by process number, not *priority*? The point of a priority queue is to handle prioritisation for you, surely?

Comment: If a process has priority 3, it is added to the prio3 queue. That queue is sorted by pid because the process with the lowest pid needs to run first, in that priority.

Comment: Please could you describe the rules for prioritising your processes. Is the decision to have a queue per priority your own, or one that you have been asked to follow?

Comment: Why not just use a single queue with a Comparator that sorts by priority first and PID second?

Comment: added section to the post to address comments